# php filter with more than one dropdown without submit button

Tags: php, mysqli, drop-down-menu

I have a product display page and I need to filter products according to filters such as product family type etc… without having a submit button. I got the code to filter using the single drop-down list but can't use for multiple drop-down lists.

Here's my code, code for drop-down list:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" id="fil" >
    <form method="post" id="report_filter" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" >
        <select name="name" onchange="document.getElementById('report_filter').submit();">
            <option>Product Family</option>
            <?php 
                $qry="select * from productfamily";
                $ex=mysqli_query($con,$qry);
                while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($ex))
                {
                    echo "<option>".$row['prod_family']."</option>";

                }
            ?>
        </select>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" id="fil">
    <form method="post" id="report_filter" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" >
        <select name="name" onchange="document.getElementById('report_filter').submit();">
            <option>Surface Finish</option>
            <?php 
                $qry="select * from surfacefinish";
                $ex=mysqli_query($con,$qry);
                while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($ex))
                {
                    echo "<option>".$row['sur_finish']."</option>";

                }
            ?>
        </select>
    <form>
</div>
```

Code for the filter

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
    $sort = $_POST['name'];
    echo $sort;
    $qry="select * from products where prod_family='$sort' limit $start_from,$limit";
    $ex=mysqli_query($con,$qry);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($ex)>0)
    {
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($ex))
        {
            echo '<li>
                <div id="imgwrap">
                <img src="admin/'.$row['image'].'">
                </div>
                <div class="prod_title">
                    <h4>'.$row['prod_family'].'</h4>
                    <h3>'.$row['prod_name'].'</h3>

                </div>
                <div id="hoverwrap">
                    <h4 id="app">Suitable for '.$row['application'].'</h4>
                    <h4 id="color">Avalable Colors 1</h4>
                    <div class="readmorebtn">
                    <a href="viewproduct.php?prodname='.$row['prod_name'].'">View Detail</a>
                    </div>
                </div>  

            </li>';
        }
    }
}
else {
    $qry="select * from products order by prod_id asc limit $start_from,$limit";
    $ex=mysqli_query($con,$qry);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($ex)>0)
    {
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($ex))
        {
            echo '<li>
                <div id="imgwrap">
                <img src="admin/'.$row['image'].'">
                </div>
                <div class="prod_title">
                    <h4>'.$row['prod_family'].'</h4>
                    <h3>'.$row['prod_name'].'</h3>

                </div>
                <div id="hoverwrap">
                    <h4 id="app">Suitable for '.$row['application'].'</h4>
                    <h4 id="color">Avalable Colors 1</h4>
                    <div class="readmorebtn">
                    <a href="viewproduct.php?prodname='.$row['prod_name'].'">View Detail</a>
                    </div>
                </div>  

            </li>';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use js or jquery for this. U can have a standard php sql select statement. And filter that result set with jquery and/or js

Comment: You can use the jquery/Ajax for each of change in the filters, and then get the results in the response and show it in the HTML.

Comment: I am not used to with Ajax, could you please give me a sample of my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

usually, you can write javascript (ajax) inside head tag. and don't forget to attach jquery

```
    <head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
     function chg(isi){
        $.ajax({
            // this url to this page again is no problem
            url: "http://<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; ?>/code/for/the/filter.php",
            //this methos is post, so you can use $_POST['name']
            type: 'POST',
            // your code is compatible with this, can catch nams as post
            data: "name=" + isi,
            // some alert appeared but it's blank its mean its no problem
            success: function(data){
                $("#here").html(data).show;
                //to check if data error
            }
        });
     }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <select name="name" onchange="chg(this.value);">
        <option>Product Family</option>
        <?php 
            $qry="select * from productfamily";
            $ex=mysqli_query($con,$qry);
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($ex))
            {
                echo "<option>".$row['prod_family']."</option>";

            }
         ?>
     </select>
     <div class='here'></div>
     </body>
     // dont forget code for the filter down here
```

depend on the ajax script, i wrote `data: "name=" + isi` so send back to the `url` as this case is this page again, `isi` is value from your select `name='name'`

hope it'll help

Comment: hello, Thanking for your valuable time. I'm very sorry as I don't know about Ajax, Would you please tell me where to put the first code i.e function chg(isi), on the same page or another page. and could you explain the code above

Comment: Actually, my code for filter and drop-down are in a single page

Comment: @user9255196 ajax usually put inside `<head>` or everywhere as long as you write on `<script>` tag and don't forget to attach jquery because ajax is one of jquery part,,

Comment: But when using the above code, it popping up the products.php page code

Comment: you did it, then just remove the alert, and make custom code to show your data,

Comment: actually I usually build a project like your case with different page (file), it'll make you easier to define..

Comment: Sorry to ask you, I have one more doubt. Actually, I need to display products according to filters. If I click product family list the items displayed according to the list item. For that, I wrote the code (that was above-mentioned 'code for the filter' in my question). When I put that code by replacing alert, it makes nothing differently. Could you help me for this problem

Comment: have you reload the page several time.?. after you remove the alert its should not showing a popup

Comment: yes. I reload several times by removing cookies. but it popping up

Comment: the code for filter section isn't working. I just echoed hi..but its not working

Comment: the pop-up window has gone. but it doesn't show anything differently

Comment: hii...at last I made it. Thank you for your support. and I have one more doubt. In my script when <code>$("#here").html(data).show;</code>, the full page displaying in the div, but I just want to display only one section how I can do that. please let me know, I am very weak in ajax

Comment: Hi, I am sorry, have you made these one? I am little bit busy in several days.

Comment: Hi, I got it. I am extremely Thankful for your support.